# Why does a homogeneous ODE need initial condition for a particular solution while a non-homogeneous ODE doesn't?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

For homogeneous ODE's with constant coefficients you need intial conditions such as y(x0)=y0 and y'(x0)=y1
or some boundary values to find a particular solution because you need to find the constants c1 and c2 in the general solution equation y=c1  $e^{r1x}$$ +  $ c2 $e^{r2x} $ where r1 and r2 are roots of the auxillary equation.

But for non-homogeneous ODE's you can find a particular solution without having to know any intial conditions or boundary values.

Why ?

Comment: The particular solution is usually generated from an ansatz and is only required to adhere to the functional form of the underlying governing differential eqiuation. Note also, that for ODEs, Initial and Boundary conditions are only applied after you construct the full solution as the sum of the general and particular solutions. It is only for PDEs that you need homogeneous BCs, if you use Separation of Variables.

Comment: yes, we will have to apply initial value conditions after you construct the full solution as the sum of the general and particular solutions to get "the particular solution" adhering to those initial conditions

Comment: Even for PDE's you dont  *need* homogeneous BCs, even with Separation of Variables, if you can invoke a transformation to ensure homogensous BCs in the separated ODEs.

Comment: "The particular solution is usually generated from an ansatz and is only required to adhere to the functional form of the underlying governing differential eqiuation."

Yes it is generated from an ansatz but what initial condition does the 'particular solution' adhere to ?, say when finding particular solution of non-homogeneous ODE's with the undetermined coefficient method

Comment: See my comment below Prof. Israel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need initial conditions to find a particular solution of the homogeneous case.  For example, $e^{r_1 x}$ is a particular solution.

Comment: My textbook just says "one such function that solves ay" + by' +cy = 0 is $y=e^{rx}$ "
and it's from there the general formula for a solution with the 2 constants are obtained so I'm not sure how .$y=e^{rx}$ is a particular solution. Also when finding particular solution of non-homogeneous ODE's with the undetermined coefficient method, what initial condition does the 'particular solution'  adhere to ? I'm confused

Comment: $e^{rx}$ is one of the solutions - you will have 2 values of $r$ corresponding to each of the roots of the characteristic solution. The superposition of these solutions with (as yet) undetermined coefficients is the general solution. to your homogeneous ODE. If your RHS were non-zero, say $f(x)$, then you would have to seek a solution $y_p(x)$ in a functional form related to $f(x)$, such that  $y_p(x)$ satisfies your ODE. You then add this to your general solution and apply initial or boundary conditions to evaluate the coefficients.

Comment: Let's say that $f(x)=Qx^2$. What you do is set $y_p(x) = K_o + K_1 x + K_2 x^2$ and evaluate $K_0$, $K_1$ and $K_2$ by equating like terms (constant, linear and quadratic) after differentiating $y_p(x)$ twice and plugging it into the non-homogeneous ODE. For example, $cK_2= Q$ is readily apparent.

Comment: My question is this - to find a particular solution to a non-homogeneous ODE, you need to plug in initial or boundary conditions to evaluate the coefficients in the general solution equation which is y = yp + yc right ?

BUT, in the undetermined coefficients method, you just magically get the particular solution "yp" without bothering about initial or boundary values .

Is y = yp + yc with coefficients of 'yc' found out by applying initial/boundary values the particular solution or is "yp" the particular solution ?

( I noticed when coefficients are 0, y = yp )

Comment: @theenigma017, they aren't *magically determined*. They are determined from a family of functions depending on the functional form of the forcing function. See the link below.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients

Comment: I think that there's a bit of an issue with nomenclature here. The particular solution is the solution that merely satisfies the ODE, but not necessarily the initial/boundary conditions. The General Solution is the solution of the homogeneous ODE. It still doesn't satisfy ICs or BCs, but has coefficients that enable this. The COMPLETE solution is the sum of the general and particular solutions. It is only after adding these that you attempt to satisfy initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: Note that for a homogeneous ODE, your general solutions $e^{rx}$ are also particular solutions as Prof. Israel said above, but they aren't required to satisfy any conditions other than satisfying the ODE itself. This is true regardless of whether your ODE is homogeneous or not.